# Angular Material Table, on screen resize hide column dynamically and add to detail row

Tags: angular, dynamic, datatable, angular-material-table

I need to replicate Datatable Jquery behavior to Angular Material Table, when screen is zoomed out the exceeded column need to be hidden and go to detail row like this.

[Datatable jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKKMh.png)

Thanks

Tried to use Viewport without success

Comment: Reading this issue I think of all the things I do need.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using Angular so you can try using `HostListener` on `resize` and inside it using

```
var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

and checking the position of the single element. Something like that:

```
elementRect.top >= 0 &&
        elementRect.left >= 0 &&
        elementRect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        elementRect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
```

When the element is outside the viewport you can hide it and put your data in a sub table as DataTable does.